# Как заставить работать приложение?

Tags: java, android

Нужно, чтобы приложение подсчитывало среднее арифметическое `population` выбранных пользователем стран. Но сейчас приложение лишь выводит в `main3activity` 0.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
    int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
    Button btnSubmit;
    int sum;
    ListView countriesList;
    int average;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
        }
        countryData.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value));

        ListView countriesList = findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

        countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
            sum += population[i];
            average = sum / population.length;

        }


        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("average", average);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Main3Activity

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvView;
    int average;
    int defaultValue = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        average = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);
        tvView.setText("Average: " + average);
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `average = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);` использовать `average = mIntent.getExtras().getInt("average", 0);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, в main3activity все ровно приложение выдает "Average: 0"

Comment: а зачем вы "среднее" высчитываете в цикле? вы код точно свой скопировали? выведите, например в Toast, ваше среднее арифмитическое по кнопке, перед putExtra.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, нужно передать среднее значение количества population, выбранных через multiplechoice стран в main3activity. Toast не годится

Comment: что пишет в стектрейс при "выбрасывании"?

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил выше

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно изучить что такое локальные переменные и переменные класса. Лист стран и адаптер, которые ты создаёшь в методе onCreate это не тоже самое, что ты объявил как переменные класса, в итоге получается, что в методе onClick ты обращаешься к переменным класса, но они пустые(null), так как в onCreate ты создавал другие переменные и туда заносил значения, что приводило у тебя к NullPointerException. Если хочешь использовать переменные класса, то в методе onCreate необходимо убрать тип данных.

Метод onClick содержит много того, чего не нужно для решения твоей задачи. Вот я немного изменил. В начале проверка на то, что пользователь выбрал хоть одну страну, если не сделать, то будешь ловить нулл при нажатии.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    if (countriesList.getCheckedItemCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Выберите стары!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        SparseBooleanArray checked = countriesList.getCheckedItemPositions();
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
              if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
              sum += population[checked.keyAt(i)];
              }
           }
        average = sum / countriesList.getCheckedItemCount();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_AVERAGE", average);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: А и самое главное, я тоже только учусь, так что не стоит принимать мой ответ как истину в последней инстанции)

Answer (score 0):

Замени:

```
intent.putExtra("KEY_AVERAGE", average);
```

на:

```
intent.putExtra(KEY_AVERAGE, average);
```