# Передача значения в другое activity

Tags: android

Пользователь выбирает несколько стран из списка, а приложение в свою очередь передает среднее арифметическое значение population выбранных стран в main3activity. Значение должно отображатся в textview в main3activity

```
    public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    String[] countries = {"Urugay", "Paraguay", "Jamaica", "Peru", "Mexico"};
    int[] population = {6770000, 2300000, 500000, 6310000, 7000000};
    Button btnSubmit;
    int sum;
    ListView countriesList;
    int average;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Map<String, Integer> countryData = new HashMap<>(countries.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            countryData.put(countries[i], population[i]);
        }
        countryData.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " -> " + value));

        ListView countriesList = findViewById(R.id.countriesList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);

        countriesList.setAdapter(adapter);

        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < population.length; i++) {
            sum += population[i];
            average = sum / population.length;

        }


        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("average", average);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Main3Activity

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvView;
    int average;
    int defaultValue = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        average = mIntent.getIntExtra("average", 0);
        tvView.setText("Average: " + average);
    }
}
```

Но сейчас в Main3Acivity передается 0 или отображается "Average:0". как сделать правильно ?

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <ListView
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:id="@+id/countriesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/btnSubmit">
    </Button>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_main3.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main3Activity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите  манифест - может в нём что-то не так

Comment: Пробовали дебажить? 
На этой строке intent.putExtra("average", average);  average чему равно?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как заставить работать приложение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/887106/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: @RomanK., по default 0

Comment: Значит вы просто его не суммируете нигде. Необходимо дебажить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, вот manifest

Comment: @RomanK.но логически код рабочий ?

Comment: Да, по логике, вроде, ошибок нет. Манифест также нормальный. Проверьте, что у вас в переменной `average` всё ОК, вместо неё передав к-л число, `1`, например.

Comment: `@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)` - попробуйте убрать эту аннотацию и строку, на которую будет ругаться (`countryData.forEach...`). Не поможет - удаляйте приложение с аппарата, делайте `Rebuild Project` и пробуйте ещё

Comment: @woesss, оно вообще через эмулятор работает

Comment: Какая разница - эмулятор это виртуальный аппарат, в нём также есть настройки->приложения->Ваше. А под дебаггером в `onClick` `average` не `0`? Пройдите по всему коду пошагово и выясните где именно теряется/не присваивается значение.

Answer (score 2):

Есть подозрение, что сама строка-ключ `"average"` в одной активности не эквивалентна во второй (например буква `a` в одном случае русская).
Попробуйте скопировать её в `Main2Activity` и заменить в `Main3Activity`.
А лучше для ключей использовать константы:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    // объявляем константу, чтобы использовать её как ключ
    public static final String KEY_AVERAGE = "average";
```

---

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
        // передаём
        intent.putExtra(KEY_AVERAGE, average);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvView;
    int average;
    int defaultValue = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        // получаем
        average = mIntent.getIntExtra(Main2Activity.KEY_AVERAGE, 0);
        tvView.setText("Average: " + average);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ woesss, сделал. Не помогло

Comment: ну если уж делать статические константы, то через отдельный класс-контракт, использовать для этих целей одну из активити как то .. неправильно

Comment: @pavlofff, почти в любом примере от гугла, и в самом SDK ключи для экстра объявлены в классах компонентов, с которыми они используются. Лично меня такой подход устраивает больше, чем выносить одну константу в отдельный класс-контракт.

Comment: да, но они объявляются В КАЖДОМ классе одноименные, а не как у вас. Я говорю о том, что использовать одну из активити в качестве конктракта для других совсем неправильно